# is it possible to monitor the websocket connection status in browser

Tags: typescript, websocket

I am using websocket to send some instant message, now I am facing a issue that, when the user sleep the computer for a long time and wake up, the websocket connection is break up, the user must refresh the web page to reconnect the websocket. I want to auto reconnect the websocket without refresh the page or send a reconnect request. What I am tried to do is start a schedule task and read the websocket status. if the status is not connected, try 3 times to connect the websocket.

I am implement the ping/pong like this: the server side send a ping to the client for a peroid of time, the browser will automatically send pong if the connection in running. if not received the pong(for example the user sleep the computer), the server will disconnect the websocket.

is it possible to read the websocket connection status and reconnect the websocket automatically when user wake up the computer? this is the current code look like:

```
    websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
      provider.wsLastMessageReceived = time.getUnixTime()
      const encoder = readMessage(provider, new Uint8Array(event.data), true)
      if (encoding.length(encoder) > 1) {
        websocket.send(encoding.toUint8Array(encoder))
      }
      provider.emit('message', [event, provider])
    }
    websocket.onerror = (event) => {
      provider.emit('connection-error', [event, provider])
    }
    websocket.onclose = (event) => {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSocket: How to automatically reconnect after it dies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431751/websocket-how-to-automatically-reconnect-after-it-dies)